# How can I run code when a html element is added in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that adds html elements with ng-if,
I want to call a callback every time the element is added:

The html template:

```
<div ng-if="showUserConsent()" class="userConsent">
    <div class="userConsent-topBar"></div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
function ($scope, $userConsentService) {                

        this.userConsentService = $userConsentService;
        this.scope = $scope;  
        this.scope.showUserConsent = () => { return this.showUserConsent() };            

  }

    private showUserConsent(): boolean {
        return !this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage;
    }
```

I want to run some code once inner div is included, suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not want to run it as part of showUserConsent()?

Comment: showUserConsent should really be shouldShowUserConsent, meaning it is called multiple times, every digest.
I'm looking to implement a 'onShow()' that happens once

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?  If so, please mark it as answer/upvote the answer.  If not, please let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has a way to execute code when you create the ng-app, when you create a module, when a controller is referenced, and when a service is created.  As far as I know it does not support an onShow type function for a div.  There are a couple of ways you can achieve this same functionality, but without knowing more I cannot recommend "the best" one.  Here are a couple options:

Option 1:  Create a variable on the controller called isFirstTime and set it to false.  Then in showUserConsent(), check to see if HasSeenConsentMessage is false and isFirstTime is false, then run code.

```
function($scope, $userConsentService){
    this.userConsentService = $userConsentService;
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.isFirstTime = false;
    this.scope.showUserConsent = function(){
        if(!this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage && !this.isFirstTime){
            //run code
            this.isFirstTime = true;
        }
        return !this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage;
    } 
}
```

Option 2:  Use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch) to monitor changes to this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage.

```
function($scope, $userConsentService){
    this.userConsentService = $userConsentService;
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.isFirstTime = false;
    this.scope.showUserConsent = function(){
        return !this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage;
    };

    $scope.$watch('this.userConsentService.HasSeenConsentMessage', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue !== oldValue){
            //execute code here!
        }
    }
}
```